# What is setting my environment variables wrong?

Tags: r, ubuntu, boost, compilation, include-path

When I try to `install.packages('readr')`, I get errors deriving from

```
clang++ -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/lib/R/include
        -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"
        -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"
        -fpic  -g -O2  -O3 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4
        -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security 
        -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g    -std=c++11
        -c Collector.cpp -o Collector.o
```

I'm checking `~/.R/Makevars` and `/etc/R/Makeconf` for where this `clang++ -I....` command might be set but neither contains that language.

```
echo $CXX
echo $CC
```

are both empty, and setting them to something else before starting `R` hasn't helped. Starting `R --no-environ` doesn't change the error message either.

---

So where might these environment variables be set, how can I change or disable them, and how do I figure out for next time where this "global variable from somewhere" error is coming from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to include the errors you are getting.  Possibly some of the output from `sessionInfo` (e.g. R version, platform, OS).

Comment: See `R CMD config` for variables R sees, e.g., `R CMD config CXX`, `R -e "R.home('Makevars')"` for the variables defined during R installation.

Comment: Do you have boost installed? from /home/chris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/BH/include/boost/, as watching the build it is all calls to boost.

Comment: @steveb R version 3.3.1, 32-bit i686, Ubuntu precise 12.04.5

Comment: @Chris Yes, I have several versions in different places. I was thinking if I replace `-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library-BH/include"` with `-I/opt/boost_1_61_0/boost` then that might solve my problem.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thanks so much!!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

I may have needed`to add`export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/boost_1_61_0/boost/`to my`~/.bashrc`.

---

This doesn't answer my question (of how to clean the `clang` call), but changing the `CXX` value in `~/.R/Makevars` from `clang++` to `g++` did fix my immediate problem of not being able to install `readr`.

---

Here are the build errors under `clang`:

```
In file included from Collector.cpp:4:
In file included from ./Collector.h:8:
In file included from ./Token.h:6:
In file included from ./Source.h:5:
In file included from ./boost.h:13:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/support/meta_compiler.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/proto/proto.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/proto/core.hpp:21:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/proto/fusion.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/include/intrinsic.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic.hpp:23:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/swap.hpp:15:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/view/zip_view.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/view/zip_view/zip_view.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/view/zip_view/detail/begin_impl.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/algorithm/transformation/transform.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/view/transform_view/transform_view.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector10.hpp:25:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:261:61: error: 
      invalid use of 'this' outside of a nonstatic member function
            auto at_impl(J) -> decltype(at_detail<J::value>(this))
                                                            ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:262:13: error: 
      type name requires a specifier or qualifier
            {
            ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:262:13: error: 
      C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
            {
            ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:261:13: error: 
      'auto' return without trailing return type
            auto at_impl(J) -> decltype(at_detail<J::value>(this))
            ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:268:67: error: 
      invalid use of 'this' outside of a nonstatic member function
            auto at_impl(J) const -> decltype(at_detail<J::value>(this))
                                                                  ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:269:13: error: 
      type name requires a specifier or qualifier
            {
            ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:269:13: error: 
      C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
            {
            ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp:268:13: error: 
      'auto' return without trailing return type
            auto at_impl(J) const -> decltype(at_detail<J::value>(this))
            ^
8 errors generated.
make: *** [Collector.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘readr’
```

If I compile with `g++` instead of `clang++`, the errors become warnings:

```
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/is_dereferenceable.hpp:12:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/resolve.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/push.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/streambuf/indirect_streambuf.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/stream.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream/detail/iterator_source.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream/stream.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from boost.h:14,
                 from Source.h:5,
                 from Token.h:6,
                 from Collector.h:8,
                 from Collector.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/type_traits/detail/bool_trait_def.hpp:18:79: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (bool_trait_def.hpp) is deprecated
 # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (bool_trait_def.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                               ^
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/type_traits/detail/bool_trait_def.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/is_dereferenceable.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/resolve.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/push.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/streambuf/indirect_streambuf.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/stream.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream/detail/iterator_source.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream/stream.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from boost.h:14,
                 from Source.h:5,
                 from Token.h:6,
                 from Collector.h:8,
                 from Collector.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/type_traits/detail/template_arity_spec.hpp:13:84: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (template_arity_spec.hpp) is deprecated
 gma message("NOTE: Use of this header (template_arity_spec.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                               ^
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/is_dereferenceable.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/resolve.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/push.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/detail/streambuf/indirect_streambuf.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/iostreams/stream.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream/detail/iterator_source.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream/stream.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/stream.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from boost.h:14,
                 from Source.h:5,
                 from Token.h:6,
                 from Collector.h:8,
                 from Collector.cpp:4:
```

(error is too long, pasted at http://ix.io/11F0)

So `spirit` and `fusion` are disliked by both compilers (with my chosen flags, which I still can't figure out how to clean).